Can't disable "password required" when exiting my screensaver (Mac)
I recently upgraded to Sequoia 15.1 (24B83).
And now I can't disable my Mac asking for my password very time I exit the screensaver.  Under System Settings > Lock Screen the "require password" selection is set to

immediately

and it's grayed out.
I've disabled, from my iPhone, mirroring from this Mac, which I found from some Google search. But to now avail.
This isn't a huge deal, but I'd still like to go straight from screensaver back to my Mac, no password required.
What can I do?

